# Method of characteristic - what am i doing wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Problem:

$$xu_x + u^2u_y=1$$

$$u(x,0)=1$$

My attempt:

Characteristic ODEs are:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = z^2 \\
\frac{dz}{dt} = 1$$

with ICs:

$$x(0,s) = s \\
y(0,s) = 0 \\
z(0,s) = 1$$

so the solutions to ODEs come out to be:

$$x(t,s) = se^t \\
z(t,s) = t+1 \\
y(t,s) = \frac{(t+1)^{3}}{3}$$

so,

$$u(x,t) = (3y)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

this satisfies the equation but does not satisfy $u(x,0) = 1$.

In order to satisfy both the equation and $u(x,0) = 1$, I need the solution to be

$$u(x,t) = (3y+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

so help me figure out where I'm missing this '$1$'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to your $y$ equation is wrong.

You have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dt} &= u^{2} \\
&= (t + 1)^{2} \\
\implies y(t) &= \frac{(t + 1)^{3}}{3} + C
\end{align}$$

With $y(0) = 0$

$$\begin{align}
\implies y(0) &= \frac{(0 + 1)^{3}}{3} + C \\
&= \frac{1}{3} + C \\
&= 0 \\
\implies C &= \frac{-1}{3} \\
\implies y(t) &= \frac{(t + 1)^{3}}{3} - \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{align}$$

And some notational issues..

If you have reparameterised your curve using $t$, why then do you have initial conditions in $s$? It's not a big deal, but could confuse you in harder problems. Also, where did a $z$ variable come from? Your function is in $u$.. Again, not a big deal if you are aware of what you are doing, but it could confuse you when doing harder problems and can also confuse people reading your work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=1$ , letting $u(0)=0$ , we have $u=t$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x$ , letting $x(0)=x_0$ , we have $x=x_0e^t=x_0e^u$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=u^2=t^2$ , letting $y(0)=f(x_0)$ , we have $y=\dfrac{t^3}{3}+f(x_0)=\dfrac{u^3}{3}+f(xe^{-u})$

$u(x,0)=1$ :

$0=\dfrac{1^3}{3}+f(xe^{-1})$

$f\left(\dfrac{x}{e}\right)=-\dfrac{1}{3}$

$f(x)=-\dfrac{1}{3}$

$\therefore y=\dfrac{u^3}{3}-\dfrac{1}{3}$

$u^3=3y+1$